# VBA: How to delete multiple rows from an Excel table?

Tags: excel, vba

I know how to delete multiple rows when it's not a Table object (i.e. just the entire row)

```
Sub Delete()
Rows(“1:3”).EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

I also know how to delete a single row from a Table object:

```
Sub Delete()
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").ListRows(1).Delete
End Sub
```

But I'm not sure how to delete multiple rows from a Table object. Specifically, I will always need to delete rows from 1 to some `n` that the user specifies from `Table1` .

I currently have it as a for-loop in my macro to achieve this, but this is painfully slow when `n` is high. So if there's a simple adaptation of the above, that would be great?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34387929/looping-through-rows-in-a-listobject-to-delete-them-is-very-slow

Comment: Don't think the delete function let's you delete more than one row a time so you would have to create your own sub to do it like so:

  Sub DeleteRows(ListObj, rowsToDelete)
    
    x = Application.Min(rowsToDelete)
    For i = Application.Min(rowsToDelete) To Application.Max(rowsToDelete)
        ListObj.ListRows(x).Delete
    Next i
    End Sub
    
    Sub Macro1()
        Range("H8:I9").Select
        ' Delete rows 3 & 4
        DeleteRows Selection.ListObject, Array(3, 4)
    End Sub

(sorry question got closed off by the time i finished testing it out)